# Particle's in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, particles

I'm currently using this particle system and it work fine. Particle's should be destroy after cross boundry's or alpha's smaller then 0. But however sometimes when i use this code like pereatly 4 it fails and particles cant destory.

```
function init():void
{
    particleArray = [];

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrameLoop);
    createParticle(s3.whell.x,s3.whell.y);
}

function onEnterFrameLoop(event:Event):void
{
    updateParticle();
}
/**
 * createParticle(target X position, target Y position)
 */
function createParticle(targetX:Number, targetY:Number):void
{
    //run for loop based on particleTotal
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < particleTotal; i++) 
    {
        var particle_mc:MovieClip = new Particle();

        //set position & rotation, alpha
        particle_mc.x = targetX
        particle_mc.y = targetY
        particle_mc.rotation = Math.random() * 360;
        particle_mc.alpha = Math.random() * 1.1;

        //set particle boundry            
        particle_mc.boundyLeft = targetX - particleRange;
        particle_mc.boundyTop = targetY - particleRange;
        particle_mc.boundyRight = targetX + particleRange;
        particle_mc.boundyBottom = targetY + particleRange;

        //set speed/direction of fragment
        particle_mc.speedX = Math.random() * particleMaxSpeed - Math.random() * particleMaxSpeed;
        particle_mc.speedY = Math.random() * particleMaxSpeed - Math.random() * particleMaxSpeed;
        particle_mc.speedX *= particleMaxSpeed
        particle_mc.speedY *= particleMaxSpeed

        //set fade out speed
        particle_mc.fadeSpeed = Math.random()*particleFadeSpeed;

        //just a visual particle counter
        particleCurrentAmount++;

        // add to array
        particleArray.push(particle_mc);

        // add to display list
        addChild(particle_mc);
    }
}

 function updateParticle():void
{
    for (var i = 0; i < particleArray.length; i++)
    {
        var tempParticle:MovieClip = particleArray[i];

        //update alpha, x, y
        tempParticle.alpha -= tempParticle.fadeSpeed;
        tempParticle.x += tempParticle.speedX;
        tempParticle.y += tempParticle.speedY;

        // if fragment is invisible remove it               
        if (tempParticle.alpha <= 0)
        {
            destroyParticle(tempParticle);
        }
        // if fragment is out of bounds, increase fade out speed
        else if (tempParticle.x < tempParticle.boundyLeft || 
                tempParticle.x > tempParticle.boundyRight || 
                tempParticle.y < tempParticle.boundyTop || 
                tempParticle.y > tempParticle.boundyBottom)
        {
            tempParticle.fadeSpeed += 8;
            destroyParticle(tempParticle);
        }
    }
}

 function destroyParticle(particle:MovieClip):void
{
    for (var i = 0; i < particleArray.length; i++)
    {
        var tempParticle:MovieClip = particleArray[i];
        if (tempParticle == particle)
        {
            particleCurrentAmount--;
            particleArray.splice(i,1);
            removeChild(tempParticle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the problem is? so far it's entirely unclear to me what you are asking for. What is "after and after it fails" supposed to mean? **How** does it fail? What is happening? Merely stating that "it fails" is kind of useless. You wouldn't be asking here if everything was ok. Please elaborate and explain what problem you are facing.

Comment: thx for comment man i fix that i think my problem is when i use this code like repeatly (after and after :) it fails and particles cant destory and stay on the stage thats whats i try to tell u guys before :)